# React-Native Fade Out animation with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

This is a React Native app. I'm implementing "cover" component that displays an image, once video is loaded, image fades out and video is playing instead. Here is my code:

```
export default function Cover() {
    const [playVideo, setPlayVideo] = useState(false);
    const [coverOpacityAnimation] = useState(new Animated.Value(1))

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!playVideo) return;
        Animated.timing(coverOpacityAnimation, { 
            toValue: 0, 
            duration: 1000
        }).start()
    }, [playVideo])

    return (
        <View>
            <Animated.View style={{opacity: coverOpacityAnimation}}>
                <Image source={{uri: data.cover}} />
            </Animated.View>
            <Video 
                source={{uri: 'https://videostorage.net/public/video.mp4'}}
                onReadyForDisplay={() => setPlayVideo(true)} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

The issue that I'm having is, when `setPayVideo(true)` is called from Video component fading out is not happening, image just disappears and video is playing. If I do:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.timing(coverOpacityAnimation, { 
            toValue: 0, 
            duration: 1000
        }).start()
    })
```

Animation works as expected. I need to trigger it from Video `onReadyForDisplay`. New to hooks - please help :)